# Any Advice Getting into  Mixing & Mastering?

Tags: music, mixing, sound-design, career

Hi all, Happy February lol! I recently entered the graduate sound design program at the Savannah College of Art & Design after studying radio production in Undergrad. I know it's graduate school, but the sound/audio industry is so broad I'm trying to narrow down where I want focus my career in the near future. I got into the whole audio thing because of my love of music and one of the things I would love to get into is music mixing and mastering. I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas about learning more about that/getting into that industry outside of the academic environment. I've been looking into internships but they don't seem to be as common as, say, a post-house. Any advice helps, take care!

Answer (score 1):

I got my start recording and mixing music.

Get an internship at a studio in New York or LA. Learn under a pro mixer, it's really the only way to go about it without chasing your tail for 10 years learning things the hard way.

Also, the person I apprenticed under started out going to where local bands rehearsed (rehearsal stages, garages, etc.) and practiced miking them. It's easier to practice miking and recording this way as opposed to doing free albums for new bands because you don't constantly have band members begging for you to turn them up.